# CALayer.draw(in:) and CALayer.needsDisplay(forKey:) not called when expected, presentation layer unexpectedly nil

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to implement a layer with implicitly animated properties, and I am seeing some very strange behavior. Here's a simple layer that demonstrates what I mean:

```
class CustomLayer: CALayer {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        implcitlyAnimatedProperty = 0.0000
        needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
    }

    override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
        implcitlyAnimatedProperty = (layer as! CustomLayer).implcitlyAnimatedProperty
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @NSManaged
    var implcitlyAnimatedProperty: CGFloat

    override func action(forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        if event == "implcitlyAnimatedProperty" {
            let action = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event)
            action.fromValue = presentation()?.value(forKey: event) ?? implcitlyAnimatedProperty
            return action
        } else {
            return super.action(forKey: event)
        }
    }

    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == "implcitlyAnimatedProperty" {
            return true
        } else {
            return super.needsDisplay(forKey: key)
        }
    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        if presentation() == nil {
            print("presentation is nil")
        }
        print(presentation()?.value(forKey: "implcitlyAnimatedProperty") ?? implcitlyAnimatedProperty)
    }
}
```

I create an instance of `CustomLayer` and attempt to animate the property implicitly like this:

```
        let layer = CustomLayer()
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer) // I'm doing this in a view controller, when a button is pressed
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(false)
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(10)
        layer.implcitlyAnimatedProperty = 10 // (1)
        layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100) // (2)
        CATransaction.commit()
```

The behavior that I'm seeing is as follows:

- With the code exactly as it's written above, the first time `draw(in:)` is called, `presentation()` returns `nil`, which, in my real app, makes the layer draw once with the final values from the model layer, which is an undesirable visual artifact. Otherwise, everything works as expected.
- With (2) commented out, `needsDisplay(forKey:)` is never called after the layer is created, and `draw(in:)` is never called. `action(forKey:)` *is* called, however.

A common explanation for these functions not being called is that the layer has a delegate which is handling these calls on its behalf. But the layer's delegate is nil here, so that can't be what's happening.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Your layer isn't drawn, because it has empty bounds and is invisible. You should move (2) before the transaction instead of removing it.

Some notes to your code:

You shouldn't write initializers to set your properties. Overwrite `defaultValue(forKey:)` instead:

```
override class func  defaultValue(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
    if key == "implcitlyAnimatedProperty" {
        return 0.0
    }
    else {
        return super.defaultValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

The setters of layer properties have some surprising features and side effects. E.g. when you set a property inside of a transaction the method `action(forKey:)` is called *before* the value is applied to the properties. Thus you may simplify the line

```
action.fromValue = presentation()?.value(forKey: event) ?? implcitlyAnimatedProperty
```

to

```
action.fromValue = implcitlyAnimatedProperty
```

`presentation()` may return `nil`in `draw(in:)`, because `self` may be the presentation layer of your (model) layer. Check `model()` it will return the layer you have created.

`needsDisplay(forKey:)` is a class method, it is called just once for each property. Core Animation decides only once for all layer instances, if a property is animatable.

Comment: Thanks, this answers many of my questions. However, I'm not sure if some the details are accurate. `presentation()` *doesn't* always return nil in `draw(in:)` -- only the first time it's called.

Comment: Moreover, if I return an action for  `bounds` from `action(forKey:)`, set the frame or bounds inside of the CATransaction, then read the value of `bounds` in `draw(in:)`, `self.bounds` is equal to the model's value for `bounds`, while `presentation()?.bounds` prints the expected interpolation between the old and new values (that is, it varies between calls).